# A sentence has two verbs

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, verbs, subordinate-clauses

Sentence:

> **What's** it **mean** that the review is now a criminal probe?

The sentence has two verbs, the **is** in **What's** and **mean**.

Is this right?

Why can it be written this way?

Source: "[News Brief: DOJ Investigates Russia Probe, Impeachment Latest, Iraq Protests](https://www.npr.org/2019/10/25/773305375/news-brief-doj-investigates-russia-probe-impeachment-latest-iraq-protests)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb **is** is in a [subordinate clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subordinate_clause):

> What's it mean **that the review is now a criminal probe**?

It works like this sentence:

> Ryan Lucas **said** that the matter **is** now a criminal investigation.

"That the matter is now a criminal investigation" is the object of "said". The subordinate clause is like a sentence within a sentence. As a whole, it serves as a big noun in the main clause ("Ryan Lucas said…").

Your example sentence is slightly more complicated. It actually has three verbs, which we can see if we expand the contraction:

> What **does** it **mean** that the review **is** now a criminal probe?

Of course, **does** is only an auxiliary verb here, serving only to make the sentence a question. But you can still see two verbs if we shorten the sentence like this:

> What **does** it **mean**?

It's actually not unusual to have multiple verbs in an English sentence. Here are a few more examples:

> **Let** me **go**!
>
> You **can't teach** an old dog new tricks.
>
> Steve **should ask** Betty to **tell** Elaine to **pay** the gas bill before the gas company **shuts off** the gas and the furnace **stops** and we all **freeze**.

Comment: I get it. 'S in what's is not is, but is does. That+a sentence can be used as a noun.

Comment: Oops! With the newly edited question, I see that I misunderstood what "is" referred to in the original question. The only difficulty was the contraction of "does". I'll let this answer stand, though now I see that 90% of it is actually irrelevant. Maybe the irrelevant part is still useful.